# 2021-22 ncaa mob teams with 0 transfer players on the roster

Tags: basketball, transfer

With the transfer portal what it is, how many ncaa men teams are playing this season with no transfer players on their roster?

Comment: Are you interested in _all_ NCAA mens teams (including e.g. Division III teams) or a subset?

Comment: This is probably answerable with limitation to D1; VerbalCommits has a database that would make this relatively straightforward (just scrape their pages for 2018-present, then match up to the current rosters from sports reference or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Don't have an answer to the exact question, but in 2018, 29 teams hadn't had a transfer since the 2012 transfer portal began operation, according to [this article](https://athleticdirectoru.com/articles/investigating-college-basketballs-transfer-movement/) which based its data on the [VerbalCommits database](https://www.verbalcommits.com/transfers/2022):

[image: List of 29 teams that hadn't had a transfer as of 2018]

This is heavily populated by Ivy League teams, military academies, and other schools that would have very difficult to meet entrance requirements (like Stanford).  But a few surprises - UCLA and Florida State, for example.